# Time series and multiple variables

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, exponential-family

I created a time series in Excel (not ideal) using Holts-Winters to forecast daily loan values in a month and it works very well.

I've been asked to build a similar model that integrates other variables but other than a multiple regression model (which has it's own issues) I'm not sure with my limited experience how I could achieve this and within Excel.

Any suggestions would be most welcome

Regards

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is by using the Box-Jenkins Transfer function modeling approach as discussed in their text book called "Time Series Analysis".

You can create 6 dummies(ie 0/1 variable) representing the days of the week and 11 monthly indicators to represent seasonal effects. Now consider incorporating events such as holidays and include any lead, contemporaneous or lag effect around these known variables. Now there may be unusual values (pulses) or level shifts or local time trends in the data that you might need to identify and add these variables to the model so that the other variables have an accurate coefficient not skewed by outliers.

Furthermore the day-of-the-week effects may have changed over time e.g. there was no Saturday effect for the first 20 weeks but a Saturday effect for the last 50 weeks.If you wish to post your daily data we can try it.

Comment: Hi Tom The variables I am looking to model along with the daily loan values are daily count if customers, daily loans granted and daily loans declined is this possible in the model you are suggesting?

Comment: Yes, they would be additional regressors.

Comment: Hi @TomReilly I have tried to post the data for the month but it is too long please advise how I can send this to you to look at?

Comment: I don't think I tag you correctly in the above reply.

Comment: If you click on my profile you will see my email.  you can send it to tomreilly@autobox.com